# how to use gpu::Stream in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpgpu

OpenCV has `gpu::Stream` class that encapsulates a queue of asynchronous calls. Some functions have overloads with the additional `gpu::Stream` parameter. Aside from [gpu-basics-similarity.cpp sample code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/doc/tutorials/gpu/gpu-basics-similarity/gpu-basics-similarity.rst#id7), there is very little information in OpenCV documentation on how and when to use `gpu::Stream`. For example, it is not very clear (to me) what exactly `gpu::Stream::enqueueConvert` or `gpu::Stream::enqueueCopy` do, or how to use `gpu::Stream` as additional overload parameter. I'm looking for some tutorial-like overview of `gpu::Stream`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default all gpu module functions are synchronous, i.e. current CPU thread is blocked until operation finishes.

`gpu::Stream` is a wrapper for `cudaStream_t` and allows to use asynchronous non-blocking call. You can also read "CUDA C Programming Guide" for detailed information about CUDA asynchronous concurrent execution.

Most gpu module functions have additional `gpu::Stream` parameter. If you pass non-default stream the function call will be asynchronous, and the call will be added to stream command queue.

Also `gpu::Stream` provides methos for asynchronous memory transfers between `CPU<->GPU` and `GPU<->GPU`. But `CPU<->GPU` asynchronous memory transfers works only with page-locked host memory. There is another class `gpu::CudaMem` that encapsulates such memory.

Currently, you may face problems if same operation is enqueued twice with different data to different streams. Some functions use the constant or texture GPU memory, and next call may update the memory before the previous one has been finished. But calling different operations asynchronously is safe because each operation has its own constant buffer. Memory copy/upload/download/set operations to the buffers you hold are also safe.

Here is small sample:

```
// allocate page-locked memory
CudaMem host_src_pl(768, 1024, CV_8UC1, CudaMem::ALLOC_PAGE_LOCKED);
CudaMem host_dst_pl;

// get Mat header for CudaMem (no data copy)
Mat host_src = host_src_pl;

// fill mat on CPU
someCPUFunc(host_src);

GpuMat gpu_src, gpu_dst;

// create Stream object
Stream stream;

// next calls are non-blocking

// first upload data from host
stream.enqueueUpload(host_src_pl, gpu_src);
// perform blur
blur(gpu_src, gpu_dst, Size(5,5), Point(-1,-1), stream);
// download result back to host
stream.enqueueDownload(gpu_dst, host_dst_pl);

// call another CPU function in parallel with GPU
anotherCPUFunc();

// wait GPU for finish
stream.waitForCompletion();

// now you can use GPU results
Mat host_dst = host_dst_pl;
```

Comment: Thanks! So, in your example, gpu::Stream is used for function calls on GPU that are asynchronous from CPU function calls. But suppose that I have two independent functions (on GPU). Can I use two distinct gpu::Stream objects so that these functions will execute in parallel on a single GPU (similar to multi-threading)?

Comment: when would one use multiple streams?

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple streams. But, as I said, you may face problems if you call the same functions from different streams.

Comment: How is this valid code? Wouldn't host_src_pl be empty?

Comment: `stream.enqueueDownload` will allocate memory for `host_dst_pl`.

Comment: Can you say how this is done in OpenCV 3.1? The members `enqueueUpload` and `enqueueDownload` do no longer exist.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104433/opencv3-where-has-cvcudastreamenqueueupload-gone