# Mapped Memory and gpu::CudaMem usage

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I was wondering if it is possible to avoid memory transfer between gpu and device. I have read recently that mapped memory is for this purpose, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. How much mapped memory can be allocated?
2. When we use mapped memory the global memory of the gpu stays unused?
3. Instead of uploading data in `gpu::GpuMat` in opencv can we use `ALLOC_ZEROCOPY` in the
   [gpu::CudaMem](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html) to save uploading time like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842827/how-to-use-gpustream-in-opencv)?
4. If yes, could you please give an example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> How much mapped memory can be allocated?

It depends on the OS and how much physical memory is available. The CUDA driver allocates mapped memory from the OS non-paged pool. E.g., for 64-bit Windows 7, this can be up to 75% of the physical memory or 128GB, whichever is smaller. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx for more information.

> When we use mapped memory the global memory of the gpu stays unused?

For a discrete GPU, implied by the question, the GPU memory stays unused. See NVIDIA's whitepaper about mapped and pinned memory: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/cmd/default/download-comment-attachment/50683/

> Instead of uploading data in gpu::GpuMat in opencv can we use ALLOC_ZEROCOPY in the
>   gpu::CudaMem to save uploading time like in this?

"zerocopy" buffers are mapped and pinned. Remember that the physical reality of the memory configuration does not change when you allocate mapped and pinned memory. For a discrete GPU, data still has to be copied from the host to the device over the PCI or PCIe bus. It just happens implicitly instead of explicitly. You can write less code but probably not improve performance (on a discrete GPU).

> If yes, could you please give an example?

Can't help you on this one.

Comment: In the answer about ALLOC_ZEROCOPY you mean that the using of this memory allocation will not save as form the uploading time? In other words, the time is needed to upload an image via gpuMatIm.upload(cpuMatIm) can not be avoided or reduced with mapped memory or just pinned memory? Also what do you mean by saying _discete_ GPU? Thank you!

Comment: A discrete GPU has its own memory and data moves to and from the GPU over the PCI bus. It's common in desktop systems and is faster for graphics because memory bandwidth is not shared with the CPU. An integrated GPU shares memory with the CPU. There's typically a setting the BIOS for how much of the system memory to use for the GPU. This is often called shared memory. Not to be confused with CUDA shared memory.

Comment: So, you mean that the mapped memory is more useful in not discrete GPUs and in discrete GPUs we will have small improve in performance?

Comment: @Thoth, I guess you didn't actually read the whitepaper I linked for you? Quoting: `“Mapped” pinned buffers that are mapped into the CUDA address space. On integrated 
GPUs, mapped pinned memory enables applications to avoid superfluous copies since 
integrated GPUs operate on the same pool of physical memory as the CPU. As a result, 
mapped pinned buffers may be referred to as “zero-copy” buffers.`

Comment: And: `On discrete GPUs, mapped pinned memory is only a performance win if all memory 
transactions are coalesced. For uncoalesced memory transactions, a 2-7x reduction in PCI 
Express bandwidth will be observed.`