# OpenCV -- safe to enqueue the same function with different data on same Stream?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I'm trying to optimise my OpenCV code to run on the GPU. The problem is that there seem to be conflicting opinions on what is and isn't safe to run on the GPU.

In the thread here: [how to use gpu::Stream in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842827/how-to-use-gpustream-in-opencv) , the answer states:

> Currently, you may face problems if same operation is enqueued twice with different data to different streams.

I would be happy to solve this by enqueuing these operations onto the *same* stream. However, in the document here http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/gtc-express-itseez-opencv-webinar.pdf the author writes (slide 28):

> Current limitation:
>   – Unsafe to enqueue the same GPU operation multiple times

And he shows an example in which he states that it's unsafe to enqueue the same operation on the *same* stream, too.

I am confused -- would it be safe for me to enqueue the same operation on the same Stream, or not? Does anyone know?

Intuitively, I would have thought it to be OK, since the same stream would, I imagine, run in serial, so the two functions would never try to concurrently access the same data. But I'd really like confirmation before I implement something.

Thank you for your help!