# OpenCV3: where has cv::cuda::Stream::enqueueUpload() gone?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, opencv3.0

In former versions of OpenCV there was the function `Stream::enqueueUpload` that could be used to upload data to the GPU asynchronously together with `CudaMem` (compare: [how to use gpu::Stream in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842827/how-to-use-gpustream-in-opencv)). However, this function does no longer exist in OpenCV 3. The `CudaMem` class is also gone but seems to have been replaced by the `HostMem` class.

Can anyone tell me how to perform an asynchronous upload in OpenCV 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done now via `void GpuMat::upload(InputArray arr, Stream& stream)` method:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat d_mat;
cv::cuda::HostMem h_mat;
cv::cuda::Stream stream;
d_mat.upload(h_mat, stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: As it seems this is the correct way to do it now. What I'd still like to know: is it possible to _directly_ read an image into page locked memory with `cv::imread` to avoid the aditional `cv::Mat::copyTo`?

Comment: `cuda::HostMem` provides static `getAllocator` method, which returns `MatAllocator` object. You can use it to override default allocator for `cv::Mat` using `cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator` method. After that you can use `cv::Mat` objects instead of `cuda::HostMem`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean I should do `cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::PAGE_LOCKED));` and then every `cv::Mat` will per default be constructed with page-locked memory; thus the matrix returned by `imread` would also be page-locked? If so then **1.** How do I change `cv::Mat` back to the default allocator **2.** Instead of calling `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(cv::cuda::HostMem, cv::cuda::Stream)` then for uploading to the gpu I would have to do `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat, cv::cuda::Stream)` with my page-lock allocated `cv::Mat`?

Comment: And just to give you a general idea of what I want to do: I have a loop and in each iteration an image shall be loaded from disk, placed into page-locked memory and then uploaded to the VRAM (where it's used for processing and will then no longer be needed). At the moment I create a `HostMem` object before the loop and then, inside each iteration, get a normal `cv::Mat` via `cv::imread` which I then copy to the existing `HostMem` object by calling `cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::cuda::HostMem)`. And now I wanted to avoid that additional copyTo-call.

Comment: 1. `cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(NULL)` should back to default allocator.

Comment: 2. Yes, you can use `cv::cuda::GpuMat::upload(cv::Mat, cv::cuda::Stream)` if `cv::Mat` was allocated as page locked.

Comment: I tried to do `cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::PAGE_LOCKED)); cv::Mat image = imread(...); cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(NULL);` inside the loop, but that's slower than the way I currently do it, which is allocting page-locked memory before the loop, then reading the image regularly and then copying it over to the page-locked memory. Maybe allocating page-locked is slower?

Comment: I think writing to page-locked memory is slower.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand copying things there is also writing to page-locked memory. These allocator functions seem not to be very well documented. Do you know what `cv::Mat::getStdAllocator` does?

Comment: According to its name it returns standard Mat allocator, which uses `cv::fastAlloc`.