# GPU vs CPU end to end latency for dynamic image resizing

Tags: opencv, imagemagick, gpu, cpu, throughput

I have currently used OpenCV and ImageMagick for some throughput benchmarking and I am not finding working with GPU to be much faster than CPUs. Our usecase on site is to resize dynamically to the size requested from a master copy based on a service call and trying to evaluate if having GPU makes sense to resize per  service call dynamically.

Sharing the code I wrote for OpenCV. I am running the following function for all the images stored in a folder serially and Ultimately I am running N such processes to achieve X number of image resizes.**I want to understand if my approach is incorrect to evaluate or if the usecase doesn't fit typical GPU usecases. And what exactly might be limiting GPU performance. I am not even maximizing the utilization to anywhere close to 100%**

**resizeGPU.cpp**:
{

```
    cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator (cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::PAGE_LOCKED));

    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Mat src = imread(input_file,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    auto t_end_read = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if(!src.data){
            std::cout<<"Image Not Found: "<< input_file << std::endl;
            return;
    }

    cuda::GpuMat d_src;
    d_src.upload(src,stream);
    auto t_end_h2d = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cuda::GpuMat d_dst;

    cuda::resize(d_src, d_dst, Size(400, 400),0,0, CV_INTER_AREA,stream);
    auto t_end_resize = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Mat dst;
    d_dst.download(dst,stream);
    auto t_end_d2h = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"read,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_read-t_start).count()<<",host2device,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_h2d-t_end_read).count()
                            <<",resize,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_resize-t_end_h2d).count()
                            <<",device2host,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_d2h-t_end_resize).count()
            <<",total,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_d2h-t_start).count()<<endl;


}
```

**resizeCPU.cpp:**

```
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Mat src = imread(input_file,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    auto t_end_read = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if(!src.data){
            std::cout<<"Image Not Found: "<< input_file << std::endl;
            return;
    }

    Mat dst;
    resize(src, dst, Size(400, 400),0,0, CV_INTER_AREA);
    auto t_end_resize = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout<<"read,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_read-t_start).count()<<",resize,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_resize-t_end_read).count()
        <<",total,"<<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end_resize-t_start).count()<<endl;
```

**Compiling** : g++ -std=c++11 resizeCPU.cpp -o resizeCPU `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

I am running each program N number of times controlled by following code : runMultipleGPU.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
START=1
END=$1
for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
do
./resizeGPU "$c" &#>/dev/null #&disown;
done
wait
echo All done
```

Run : ./runMultipleGPU.sh

Those timers around lead to following aggregate data

```
No_processes    resizeCPU   resizeGPU   memcpyGPU   totalresizeGPU
1                 1.51        0.55        2.13         2.68
10                5.67        0.37        2.43         2.80
15                6.35        2.30       12.45        14.75
20                6.30        2.05       10.56        12.61
30                8.09        4.57       23.97        28.55
```

No of images run per process : 267

Average size of the image: 624Kb

According to data above, as we increase the number of processes(leading to increased number of simultaneous resizes) the resize perform
ance(which includes actual resize + host to device and device to host copy) increases significantly on GPU vs CPU.

Similar results after using ImageMagick which uses OpenCL beneath

**Code** :

```
setenv("MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE","OFF",1); //Turn in ON to use GPU acceleration
Image image;
auto t_start_read = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
image.read( full_path );
auto t_end_read = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
image.resize( Geometry(400,400) );
auto t_end_resize = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

**Results** :

```
No_procs    resizeCPU   resizeGPU
1            63.23       8.54
10           76.16      31.04
15           76.56      50.79
20           76.58      71.68
30           86.29     140.17
```

Test Machine configuration:

4 GPU (Tesla P100) - but test only utilizes 1 GPU

64 CPU cores (over Intel Xeon 2680 v4 CPU )

OpenCV version : 3.4.0

ImageMagick version : 6.9.9-26 Q16 x86_64 2018-01-17

Cuda Toolkit : 9.0

Comment: What's your question? Did you compile ImageMagick with OpenMP feature & at Q8?

Comment: Just marked my question in bold. Yes it is compiled with OpenMP and OpenCL " FEATURES = DPC Cipher OpenCL OpenMP" and it is Q16. But does Q8 vs Q16 matters in terms of working with GPUs?

Comment: Got it. Try recompiling IM libraries with Q8. The latency might be contributed to OpenCV passing 2^8 data-steams to the GPU while Magick++ is passing 2^16. Higher quantums increase quality / precision, but require more memory, and the pages of memory being copied back-n-forth might be the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @emcconville actually am not comparing openCV and Imagemagick. i am trying to tell both are giving similar results and not able to convince me that our usecase fits GPU.  I will try to get Q8.

Comment: If you are trying to get better performance, IMHO you should at least use `AVX` and `SSE` functionality by compiling with `-O3 -march=native` and also use **GNU Parallel** to control parallelism.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Looking further into those options: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/CPU-optimizations-build-options. They more look like option of improving CPU performance. My question is more related to increasing performance with GPUs in an integrated system.

Answer (score 0):

Highly propable this is too late to help you. However for people looking at this answer this is my suggestion to improve performance. The way you are setting pinned memory does not give you the boost you are looking for. 
This is: Using

```
//method 1
cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::PAGE_LOCKED));
```

In the comments of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104433/opencv3-where-has-cvcudastreamenqueueupload-gone). Somebody suggested doing as you. The person answering said that it was slower. I was timing the implementation of a sobel derivatives close to the one in [Coldvision.io Sobel](http://www.coldvision.io/2016/03/18/image-gradient-sobel-operator-opencv-3-x-cuda/) The main steps are:

1. Read color image
2. gaussian blurring of the color image using a
   radius of 3 and a delta of 1;
3. grayscale conversion;
4. computing the x and y gradiants
5. merging them into the final output image.

Instead I implemented a version swaping the order of step 2 and 3. Converting to gray scale first and then denoising the result by passing a gaussian.

I was running openCV 3.4 in windows 10. Cuda 9.0. My CPU is an i7-6820HQ. GPU is a Quadro M1200.

I try your method and this one:

```
//Method 2
//allocate pinned memory    
cv::cuda::HostMem memory(siz.height, siz.width, CV_8U, cv::cuda::HostMem::PAGE_LOCKED);
//Read input image from the disk
Mat input = imread(input_file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if (input.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Image Not Found: " << input_file << std::endl;
    return;
}    
input.copyTo(memory);
// copy the input image from CPU to GPU memory
cuda::GpuMat gpuInput;
cv::cuda::Stream stream;
gpuInput.upload(memory, stream);

//Do your processing... 

//allocate pinned memory for output
cv::cuda::HostMem outMemory(siz.height, siz.width, CV_8U, cv::cuda::HostMem::PAGE_LOCKED);
gpuOutput.download(outMemory, stream);
cv::Mat output = outMemory.createMatHeader();
```

I calculated the gain as: `(t1-t2)/t1*100`. Where t1 is the time running the code normally. t2 running it using pinned memory. The negative values is when the method is slower than running in non-pinned memory.

```
image size  Gain % Method 1    Gain % Method 2
800x600     2.9                8.2
1280x1024   2.5                15.3
1600x1200   0.2                7.0
2048x1536   -2.3               14.6
4096x3072   -1.0               17.2
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply. Unfortunately i have lost my access to GPU boxes currently but will post once i get access